# Class transformer not converting to array of numbers

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I have a DTO in which I have a field which is an array of numbers. These ids are coming via API query parameters. I am using Class Transformer to transform these ids into an array of numbers. But I am getting an array of strings only. My DTO class is as below.

```
export class EvseGetQueryDto {
  ...
  ...

  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  @IsNumber({}, {each: true})
  @ApiProperty({ type: [Number] })
  @Type(() => Number)
  locations?: number[];

  ...
  ...
}
```

My Controller code looks like this.

```
async GetAll(@Query() query: EvseGetQueryDto): Promise<EvseDto[]> {
    return await this.evseService.GetAll(query);
}
```

If I call my controller like this below, I am still getting `['1', '2']` in my locations field.

```
http://localhost:3000/evses?locations[]=1&locations[]=2
```

Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Query parameters always come in as strings, as do URL parameters if you use those. The `@Type(() => Number)` is enough to modify this though, but you need to make sure you have `transform: true` set in your `ValidationPipe`.

```js
import {  Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsArray, IsNumber } from 'class-validator';

export class NumbersQuery {
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsArray()
  @IsNumber({}, {each: true})
  numbers: number[];
}
```

```js
import { Controller, Get, Query, UsePipes, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { NumbersQuery } from './numbers';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(@Query() query: Record<string, unknown>): string {
    return this.appService.getHello(query);
  }

  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
  @Get('numbers')
  getNumbers(@Query() numbers: NumbersQuery) {
    console.log(numbers);
    return numbers.numbers;
  }
}
```

```
▶ curl http://localhost:3000/numbers/\?numbers\[\]\=1\&numbers\[\]\=2
[1,2]%
```

```
[Nest] 76497   - 10/23/2020, 10:40:47 AM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 76497   - 10/23/2020, 10:40:47 AM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +11ms
[Nest] 76497   - 10/23/2020, 10:40:47 AM   [RoutesResolver] AppController {}: +5ms
[Nest] 76497   - 10/23/2020, 10:40:47 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 76497   - 10/23/2020, 10:40:47 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/numbers, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 76497   - 10/23/2020, 10:40:47 AM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +1ms
NumbersQuery { numbers: [ 1, 2 ] }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jay! I found the issue after you explained this stuff. I was missing a validation Pipe in my controller.

Answer (score 5):

if you don't like your search queries to look like

```
/evses?locations[]=1&locations[]=2
```

and want something like passing an entire list

```
/evses?locations=1,1
```

use inside your class

```
export class yourclass {


    @Transform(({ value }) => value.toString().split(',').map(Number))
    locations:Number[];

}
```